# caffe - how to properly train alexnet with only 7 classes

Tags: deep-learning, caffe

I have a small dataset collect from imagenet(7 classes each class with 1000 training data). I try to train it with alexnet model. But somehow the accuracy just cant go any higher(about 68% maximum). I remove conv4 and conv5 layer to prevent model overfitting also decrease the number of neuron in each layer(conv and fc). here is my setup.[image]

Did i do anything wrong so that the accuracy is so low?

Comment: Are you using pre-trained model or training it from scratch ?

Comment: Any answer depends greatly on the characteristics of your data set.  How distinct are the classes?  Did you try this with the conv4 and conv5 in place?  When you flatten the topology like this, you surrender some sophistication in feature recognition, which might be your problem.  Can you post a visualization of the remaining conv kernels?

Comment: Also, consider using CONVNET instead of an AlexNet derivative.  CONVNET is closer to the problem set you're using; it's built to handle 10 classes.

Comment: @Prune what is the that CONVNET you are talking about? please tell me.

Comment: @Harjatin in my case i have to train it from scratch due to some problem. i know if i load the pretrain model trained on imagenet it will be so much better. But is there anyway that i can let the accuracy higher from scratch? please help.

Comment: @Prune a very interesting thing is that i'm actually doing the research on feature visualisation. according to the research by [mathew zeiler,2013], each neuron suppose to be activated by particular things (like wheel, face etc) but in my case the feature doesn't converge well(its activate by different class, although those thing is a bit similar in geometric). i did spend alot  of time dealing with the data, trying to make each class more distinct and prevent similar class(like dog and cat). Is there any idea that you can provide for me to train the network for better visualisation result?

Comment: @Prune I have use caffenet as model. the accuracy went high a little bit. but the visualisation result still bad.(still not converge well) i guess its because my training data is too less....i really need to cut down the neuron in order to see the visualisation result and prevent duplicate features. is it possible to load a pretrain caffe model with less neuron for each layer?

Comment: @pwan what is the reason for you being unable to use a pre-trained model ?

Comment: @pwan: No, you cannot load a slice of a pre-trained model.  The layers and kernels are too interdependent for this to be functional.  Even if they were functional, you'd have to write your own loader with full knowledge of the saved model format.

Comment: i cant load a pretrain model is because i want to see the impact of imbalance data(i made those distribution myself) to convnet.

Answer (score 0):

I want to sort out a few terms:

(1) A perceptron is an individual cell in a neural net.

(2) In a CNN, we generally focus on the kernel (filter) as a unit; this is the square matrix of perceptrons that forms a psuedo-visual unit.

(3) The only place it usually makes sense to focus on an individual perceptron is in the FC layers.  When you talk about removing some of the perceptrons, I *think* you mean kernels.

The most important part of training a model is to make sure that your model is properly fitted to the problem at hand.  AlexNet (and CaffeNet, the BVLC implementation) is fitted to the full ImageNet data set.  Alex Krizhevsky and his colleagues spent a *lot* of research effort in tuning their network to the problem.  You are *not* going to get similar accuracy -- on a severely reduced data set -- by simply removing layers and kernels at random.

I suggested that you start from CONVNET (the CIFAR-10 net) because it's much better tuned to this scale of problem.  Most of all, I strongly recommend that you make constant use of your visualization tools, so that you can detect when the various kernel layers begin to learn their patterns, and to see the effects of small changes in the topology.

You need to run some experiments to tune and understand your topology.  Record the kernel visualizations at chosen times during the training -- perhaps at intervals of 10% of expected convergence -- and compare the visual acuity as you remove a few kernels, or delete an entire layer, or whatever else you choose.

For instance, I expect that if you do this with your current amputated CaffeNet, you'll find that the severe losses in depth and breadth greatly change the feature recognition it's learning.  The current depth of building blocks is not enough to recognize edges, then shapes, then full body parts.  However, I could be wrong -- you do have three remaining layers.  That's why I asked you to post the visualizations you got, to compare with published AlexNet features.

**edit: CIFAR VISUALIZATION**

CIFAR is much better differentiated between classes than is ILSVRC-2012.  Thus, the training requires less detail per layer and fewer layers.  Training is faster, and the filters are not nearly as interesting to the human eye.  This is not a problem with the Gabor (not Garbor) filter; it's just that the model doesn't have to learn so many details.

For instance, for CONVNET to discriminate between a jonquil and a jet, we just need a smudge of yellow inside a smudge of white (the flower).  For AlexNet to tell a jonquil from a cymbidium orchid, the network needs to learn about petal count or shape.

Comment: hey. just curious about why is removing neuron in conv layer is not meaningful. for what i consider is that the neuron(filter) in conv layer is the feature that extract(or learn) by our domain data. my idea is that, i have my data. i train my data and visualize the conv layer to see what it learn by deconv network. So I really should remove some neuron in each layer for smaller scale of neuron. think about this, if i have 384 neuron(feature) in a layer. how can i explain the impact of imbalance data on convnet feature learning. does it make sense to you? please answer, thanks!

Comment: That's why I wanted to clarify the terminology.  I see the problem now: you are using "neuron" as synonymous to "filter".  This is not correct: a neuron is a single cell in a filter matrix.  For instance, a 64x64 filter contains 4096 neurons.  Removing a single neuron would be difficult, and generally non-functional.

Comment: i guess i know what you mean. all i refer here is not neuron, instead im talking about filter!

Comment: hey, i use the cifar default setup. and the accuracy goes to 80%. i i think its so much better.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  CIFAR is built for 10 classes, with good separation.  You can experiment with the topology a little to try for slightly better performance.  Actual CIFAR results are significantly better than 80%.

Comment: just 1 more question. After I use the cifar model, the acurracy goes so much higher(68%-->86%) with my domain. However, the result of visualisation(deconv result) are really blur. in the cifar model there are so much less filter in conv1 and conv2, is it because that of the less number of filters that cause the visualization results of conv3 really blurs due to lack of good garbor filter?